# DeleteFile() doesn't work in Embarcadero C++ Builder

Tags: c++, pdf, constructor

I load several pdfs into Embarcadero C++ and digitally sign them with Gnostice pdfToolkit Vcl. The problem is deleting the unsigned pdf when it is already signed.
This is the code:

```
gtPDFDocumento->LoadFromFile("no_firmado.pdf");
gtPDFDocumento->AddSignature(firma_digital.pfx);
gtPDFDocumento->SaveToFile("firmado.pdf");

//You have to reload the pdf because if it does not give an error
gtPDFDocumento->LoadFromFile("firmado.pdf");
//
if(!DeleteFile("no_firmado.pdf"){
    int e = GetLastError();
    AnsiString error = SysErrorMessage(e);
    ShowMessage(error);
    return;
}
```

This is the result of the error with `GetLastError()`:

> The process does not have access to the file because it is being used
> by another process.

I would like to know how I can unlock the unsigned pdf in order to delete it.

I had already tried that code and it gives the same error:

```
gtPDFDocument->LoadFromFile("not_signed.pdf");
gtPDFDocument->AddSignature(digital_signature.pfx);
gtPDFDocument->SaveToFile("signed.pdf");

//You have to reload the pdf because if it does not give an error
gtPDFDocument->LoadFromFile("signed.pdf");
//
// Free Resources
gtPDFDocument->Reset();
// Destroy PDF document object
FreeAndNil(gtPDFDocument);
// After this point gtPDFDocument can not be used unless reinitialized.
if(!DeleteFile("not_signed.pdf"){
inte = GetLastError();
AnsiString error = SysErrorMessage(e);
ShowMessage(error);
return;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Is the `""no_firmado.pdf"` a copy / paste error or a typo creating the question because the `""` part is wrong?

Comment: To unlock the unsigned PDF that is locked by another process, have the other process relinquish its lock on the unsigned PDF.

Comment: if you want to see what has the file open (my guess is your app) then put a breakpoint just before the delete. And while it is paused there run the sysinternals 'handle' tool, it will show you how has it open

Answer (score 1):

You still have the `no_firmado.pdf` file open from the line where you load it originally.

```
gtPDFDocumento->LoadFromFile("no_firmado.pdf");
```

This is why you are getting this error.

Close the file explicitly and after that, it can be deleted.

```
 // Free Resources
 gtPDFDocumento->Reset();

 // Destroy PDF document object
 FreeAndNil(gtPDFDocumento);
 // After this point gtPDFDocumento can not be used unless reinitialized.
```

Now you can call `DeleteFile(...)`

Comment: I have used the resource monitor and it shows that the pdf is occupied by the application itself, I don't know how to release it

Comment: Have you tried the example in my answer? Have you read the documentation for the PDF library you use?

Comment: I have already solved it.
gtPDFDocument->Reset(); it has to go after gtPDFDocument->SaveToFile() for it to delete.